# assigning recursive function to a variable in scala

Tags: scala

Below code gives me error of
**Multiple markers at this line
    - recursive value factWithTailRec needs type
    - Implicit conversions found: i => int2bigIn**

```
@tailrec
 val factWithTailRec = (i:Int, acc:BigInt) =>   if(i == 0) 1  else factWithTailRec(i-1, i * acc)
```

Could please suggest how can I prevent it.
Requirement is to assign val to a recursive function

Answer (score 5):

As the error says:

> Multiple markers at this line - recursive value factWithTailRec
>   **needs type** - Implicit conversions found: i => int2bigIn

In other words, you need to add a type signature to the `val`:

```
val factWithTailRec: (Int, BigInt) => BigInt = (i:Int, acc:BigInt) =>   if(i == 0) 1  else factWithTailRec(i-1, i * acc)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks for help
I am little more curious, can I pass curried function to a val as well ? like below though it show error.
val factWithTailRec: (BigInt)(BigInt) => BigInt = (i:BigInt)(acc:BigInt=1) =>   if(i == 0) 1  else factWithTailRec(i-1, i * acc)